# How to use a zenity progress bar with cclive

Tags: command-line, scripts, zenity

I tried to use a zenity progress bar with cclive. I'm writting a script to download web videos files and I wanna see the progression of the download.

But when I try something like

```
$cclive <url> 2>&1 | zenity --progress
```

But when I execute the command line but it not seems to work. Any idea of how I can do that ?

BR,

[Edit]

cclive have this kind of output :

```
cclive http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo

Checking ... .......... ..........done.
youtubevideo.flv 2.5M 75.8K/s 00:09:29 5%
```

So I need to send the last part to sdout but I dont know how. Else and about pulsate, we can't see th progression with this option, and I really need it... So I will not using pulsate for this script.

---

think that the paste  `| zenity --progress` after commands - will not work.

You know that it's loaded only at the end of downloading.

I try to use zenity with `--percentage` parameter, and i know the best way to check state of process.

In my script I know size of file.

```
size_t=$theoretical_size_of file     # I don't know where are from you take FULL size     of your file. I know it in myself script.
size_r=`du -b /tmp/$filename`
perc=$[$size_t/$size_r*100]
```

Where should i write `zenity --progress --percentage=$perc`

AND i think that it should be a loop, cause `du -b` continiously changing...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how `cclive` works, but in order to make `zenity` display a progress bar, it needs to send percentages to stdout.

Here's an example:

```
# This works:
(for i in $(seq 0 3 100); do echo "$i"; sleep 0.1; done) | zenity --progress

# This doesn't:
(for i in $(seq 0 3 100); do echo "hi"; sleep 0.1; done) | zenity --progress
```

Unless you can arrange for `cclive` to do that, you'll have to settle for

```
zenity --progress --pulsate
```

---

### Edit

Based on the comments, here's some additional info. I can't give you an exact answer since apparently `cclive` is broken on Maverick. At any rate, I only get errors when I try to use it.

The first thing you need to do is to get `cclive` to print a percentage somewhere. I'm assuming the logfile will print such a percentage, but I can't test it. Then, you need to parse that output and send it to `zenity`. Here's an example (untested, or course) script:

```
#!/bin/bash

url="$1"
tmp="/tmp/cclive.log"

mkfifo "$tmp"
cclive --background --logfile="$tmp" "$url"
egrep '[0-9]+%$' < "$tmp" | zenity --progress
rm "$tmp"
```

If `cclive`'s output is in a different format, just adjust the script as appropriate. If `cclive` doesn't dump percentages to the logfile, try changing the `cclive` command to:

```
cclive "$url" > "$tmp" &
```

One final thing: You probably shouldn't send stderr out stdout (`2>&1`). Zenity will consume stdout, but you probably don't want it to eat all error messages.

### Edit 2

You might have to throw `awk` in somewhere in the pipeline so you can isolate the percentage. The basic syntax is:

```
awk '{print $1}' # change $1 to the correct space-separated field
```

In testing, I couldn't make it work correctly, but since I can't make `cclive` work, I can't really troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thx mssever,

In fact cclive have this kind of output 

`cclive http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=youtubevideo

Checking ... .......... ..........done.
youtubevideo.flv                                                                        2.5M  75.8K/s  00:09:29   5%`

So I need to send the last part to sdout but I dont know how. 

Else and about pulsate, we can't see th progression with this option, and I really need it... So I will not using pulsate for this script ;)

Comment: @Winael: I've updated my answer to reflect the additional information you gave. Please edit the original question.

Comment: Hi Scott,Thx for your answer. I tried it yesterday but it didn't work. The progress bar don't progress... So tonight I'll try to redirect the outpout of egrep/awk command to a file to check if my args is good to isolate the percents. I'll let you know...