# How to show "live" progress of ffmpeg process with zenity (or yad, or kdialog)?

Tags: scripts, video, ffmpeg, dialog, zenity

I have a script to cut/trim media files - initial details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/744011/341192) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1465674/925128); after some more recent adjustments [adjustments](https://discuss.kde.org/t/change-script-so-that-input-file-gets-already-open-when-selected-in-dolphin/5097?u=cipricus) it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=$1

eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1

DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))

$(ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT")
(for i in $(seq 0 3 100); do echo "$i"; sleep 0.1; done) | zenity --progress --width=400 --auto-close
    
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
kdialog --msgbox "Process completed successfully!"
  else
kdialog --msgbox "SOMETHING WENT WRONG!"
fi
```

It includes a line to show the progress of ffmpeg process with zenity.

```
~$ zenity --help-progress
Usage:
  zenity [OPTION…]

Progress options
  --progress                                        Display progress indication dialog
  --text=TEXT                                       Set the dialog text
  --percentage=PERCENTAGE                           Set initial percentage
  --pulsate                                         Pulsate progress bar
  --auto-close                                      Dismiss the dialog when 100% has been reached
  --auto-kill                                       Kill parent process if Cancel button is pressed
  --no-cancel                                       Hide Cancel button
  --time-remaining                                  Estimate when progress will reach 100%
```

but just using `zenity --progress --percentage=1` shows no real progress, the only useful option seems to be to use `--pulsate`, which at least shows something is happening with a line that goes back and forth.

```
ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT" | zenity --width=400 --progress --pulsate --text="Running" --percentage=1 --auto-close --auto-kill
```

[image]

Trying to mimic [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/40614/925128) answer I do get a progress bar, but that is shown *after* the process has ended and the progress itself has nothing to do with the real process.

```
$(ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT")
(for i in $(seq 0 3 100); do echo "$i"; sleep 0.1; done) | zenity --progress --width=400
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

When I try to use something like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/931015/925128), and the script is adjusted
like this

```
#!/bin/bash

(

INPUT=$(kdialog --getopenfilename ~/Videos/ '*.m4a *.ogg *.mp3 *.mp4 *.avi *.aac *.flac *.avi *.mkv *.mp4')

echo "5"
eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
[[ -z $START || -z $END || -z $OUTPUT ]] && exit 1
DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="$END")-$(date +%s --date="$START")))

echo "5"
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))
echo "10"
echo "# Running processing task." ; sleep 1
echo "35"
echo "# Running processing task." ; sleep 1
echo "60"
echo "# Running processing task." ; sleep 1
echo "85"
echo "# Running processing task." ; sleep 1
echo "99"
echo "# Running processing task." ; sleep 1

ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT"

echo "# All finished." ; sleep 1
echo "100"
```

I get a progress bar but the progress bar is shown *before* the actual process takes place.

---

The question is:

*How to have something like in the image above, but synchronized in real time with the actual `ffmpeg` process?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I only use `ffmpeg` when I need to and that's it as far as my experience with it goes, so take that part with a pinch of salt ... So, I looked into it and noticed some output that looks like `time=00:00:00:0.0` and figured out that it can be used for your purpose.

This is going to be ugly ... However, consider it a template or a boiler plate.

Using your `$DIFF`(*needs to be in seconds only like e.g. `130` and **not** in full time format like `00:02:10`*) variable (Progress bar only)

```
ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT" 2>&1 |
grep --line-buffered -Po "(?<=time=)[0-9:.]*" |
while read -r line; do echo "$line" |
awk -v offset="$DIFF" -F: 't=($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 {print t / offset * 100}'; done |
zenity --progress
```

... and with the text output as well

```
ffmpeg -ss "$START" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "$OUTPUT" 2>&1 |
while read -r line; do grep -Po "(?<=time=)[0-9:.]*" <<<"$line" |
awk -v offset="$DIFF" -F: 't=($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 {print t / offset * 100}'; echo "# $line"; done |
zenity --progress --width="500"
```

More related explanation can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1477618

Also the above two examples use `zenity` and they should work with either `kdialog` or `yad` but you shouldn’t mix them together (when doing the same one task) and you don’t need the "gun without safety switch" `eval` used here and you don’t want it either ... To know how bad that could be, try what you have in your script in the terminal like so:

```
eval $(yad --width=400 --form --field=start --field=end --field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}" | awk -F'|' '{printf "START=%s\nEND=%s\nOUTPUT=\"%s\"\n", $1, $2, $3}')
```

... and enter this in the first field:

```
; for f in "$HOME"/*/*; do echo "Removing $f"; done;
```

... and click OK ...

I bet you didn't like it ... It was harmless because I'm a nice person :-) but you could imagine what a bad person might do and you get the point.

You can however do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT="$1"

readarray -d "|" -t selection < <(yad --width=400 --form --field="start" --field="end" \
--field="output":SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "${INPUT/%.*}-out.${INPUT##*.}")
[[ -z "${selection[0]}" || -z "${selection[1]}" || -z "${selection[2]}" ]] && exit 1

DIFF=$(($(date +%s --date="${selection[1]}")-$(date +%s --date="${selection[0]}")))
OFFSET=""$(($DIFF / 3600)):$(($DIFF / 60 % 60)):$(($DIFF % 60))


ffmpeg -nostdin -loglevel trace -ss "${selection[0]}" -t "$OFFSET" -i "$INPUT" -c copy "${selection[2]}" 2>&1 |
grep --line-buffered -Po "(?<=time=)[0-9:.]*" |
while read -r line; do echo "$line" |
awk -v offset="$DIFF" -F: 't=($1 * 3600) + ($2 * 60) + $3 {print t / offset * 100}'; done |
zenity --progress --width="600" \
--text="Cropping file: (${INPUT})\nFrom (time): (${selection[0]})\nTo (time): (${selection[1]})\nFor (seconds): (${DIFF})\nOutput file: (${selection[2]})" \
--time-remaining
```

**Technical notice** `ffmpeg` seems to act differently regarding the above mentioned output i.e. `time=00:00:00:0.0` which it seams to print in some interactive(auto-updating) form that is being held until the end of the process when the output is being piped ... It, however, seems to be immediately sent through the pipe when there are other printed messages (warnings, info, errors ... etc.) as these seem to force flushing the standard streams buffers ... Therefore, increasing the `-loglevel` to `trace` seems to do the trick and force real-time status bar ... This, however, will need tuning if in addition you want to show the output as well in the `zenity` window as you'll need to do some messages filtering (*those trace messages contain all sorts of output including numbers which will mess up the accuracy of the status bar*).

Comment: (I have added the script to the question.) - If I'm not mistaken, I'm supposed to replace my lines that start with `$(ffmpeg -ss...` and `(for i in...`. If I do that, the "progress bar only" shows [this](https://i.imgur.com/duvt8Va.png), the "text output" one gives [this](https://i.imgur.com/hncZBsV.png): there's no change *during* progress. - I was expecting a progress bar like in last image in the question, but I can add `--pulsate` to give impression of progress :)

Comment: @cipricus Correct ... However, your `$OFFSET` seems to expand to something like `00:00:00` so I suggest you use `$DIFF` iinstead as the value needs to be only seconds with no `:` ... Please check the updated answer now ... Also make sure the output filename doesn't already exist or `ffmpeg` will wait in the background for confirming overwriting that file.

Comment: `needs to be only seconds with no :` - You mean I have to change the line `eval $(yad ...` after `--field=output:SFL "00:00:00" "00:00:00"`? If yes, can you indicate how to? I much prefer to enter time in the present format, instead calculating in secs a fragment in the middle of a video...

Comment: You see, I'm rather satisfied with the way things are after your proposals, and with `zenity --progress --pulsate --width=400 --auto-close`

Comment: `make sure the output filename doesn't already exist or ffmpeg will wait in the background for confirming overwriting that file` - noted

Comment: @cipricus "You mean I have to change the line…" … No, but rather make sure the value passed to `awk` as a shell variable e.g. `$DIFF` is only seconds … And `eval` can be evil in this context allowing for dangerous command injection … I'll expand on that when I have time and probably rewrite your script to show real-time progress (not just pulsating) safely … Hopefully today :-)

Comment: @cipricus I had little time today … So, I quickly updated the answer, but I'm still not satisfied with the real-timeness of the status bar in some tests (although it starts and finishes with the actual `ffmpeg` process accurately) … I'll probably look into it again, hopefully soon.

Comment: @cipricus Now, if you're satisfied, I will be satisfied and stop here ... Please, let me know what you think ... Check the updated answer and the example script at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't interact  directly with ffmpeg this way I'd recommend to use some script.
In my [Videocut](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut) project am using python [here](https://github.com/kanehekili/VideoCut/blob/master/src/Cutter.py) Line (397) ff to parse the data from an ffmpeg output.

In addition that project offers an executable (remux5 - in the ffmpeg folder) that enhances the ffmpeg cutting (Its based on ffmpegs libraries). Since I need to know the progress, it displays them. You are free to use it. If you have questions, open an issue on that project

Comment: Very nice! (Small note: there is a small error in the instructions to install from PPA, the install line contains "install" twice.)

Comment: Thanks, is fixed now

Comment: In fact I already had your tool on my computer, which I see as an alternative to something like LosslessCut. My script is intended for a much more basic use, when I very quickly want to cut something. Of course I'll try your tool from now on, but for the purpose of this Q sorrily I don't know how to adapt my script based on your lines.

Comment: The c script (remux 5) does the fast cut. It does not depend on qt. But @Raffa brings it down to point: you have to parse the output, which my example should show